# Copy from one table to another

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I need to copy everything from one table to another. I thought a simple line of SQL would have worked but apparently not.

**Code:**

```
CurrentDb.Execute "SELECT * INTO _tmp_table2 FROM _tmp_table"
```

**Error:**
_tmp_table2 already exists

I am copying from one table to another because the table its being copied into has a field set to primary key. How can I import and keep my table dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a table that does exist.

Try to append:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO _tmp_table2 SELECT * FROM _tmp_table"
```

Comment: This worked perfectly - Thank you. However, the table is cleared after each session so I need the primary keys to reset back to zero, instead of clearing the table and the next import it start from 500. Any help on that?

Comment: The easy method would be to delete the table when finished, then use your original "create table" SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the help